# Doctrine - create entity to foreign table

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, psql

Is it possible to create **entity to postgres foreign table**? Always when I want to create `doctrine:migration:diff` migration tool generate sql to delete foreign tables becouse the entity isn't created for this table.

Comment: Use [`schema_filter`](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables) to make the schema tool ignore tables.

Comment: thanks msg, I have to check it out